# Proof that the tensor product of $n$ vector spaces and a vector space can be written as the tensor product of $n+1$ vector spaces

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

Given $n + 1$ vector spaces $V_1, \ldots, V_{n + 1}$, a tensor product
$\langle V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n, \otimes_n \rangle$ of $V_1, \ldots,
V_n$ and a tensor product $\langle (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n) \otimes
V_{n + 1}, \otimes \rangle$ of $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n, V_{n + 1}$, I
want to prove that there exist a tensor product $\langle (V_1 \otimes \cdots
\otimes V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1}, \otimes_{n + 1} \rangle$.

Here I use the following definition of a tensor product (see Finite
Dimensional Multilinear Algebra from Marvin Marcus):

$\langle X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_m, \otimes \rangle$ is a tensor product
of $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ if:

1. $X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_m$ is a vector space
2. $\otimes : \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}} X_i \rightarrow X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_m$ is a
   multilinear mapping
3. (universal property) If $\varphi : \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}} X_i
   \rightarrow U$ is a multilinear mapping then there exists a unique linear mapping $h :
   X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_m \rightarrow U$ such that $h \circ \otimes =
   \varphi$
4. $X_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_m = {span} \left( \otimes \left(
   \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}} X_i \right) \right)$

Now for the proof:

1. $(V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1}$ is a vector space
   because $\langle (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1},
   \otimes \rangle$ is a tensor product.
2. Define $\otimes_{n + 1} : \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n + 1 \}} V_i
   \rightarrow (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1}$ by $\otimes_{n
   + 1} (v_1, \ldots, v_{n + 1}) = \otimes \left( \otimes_n (v_1, \ldots, v_n) {,
   v_{n + 1}}  \right)$ then by the multilinearity of $\otimes$ and $\otimes_n$
   it follows trivially that $\otimes_{n + 1}$ is multilinear.
3. (universal property) Here I'm stuck. How should I prove that, given a
   multilinear mapping $\varphi : \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n + 1 \}} V_i
   \rightarrow U$, there exist a linear mapping $h : (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes
   V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1} \rightarrow U$ such that $h \circ \otimes_{n + 1} =
   \varphi$

Using the hints provided, I think that I have found the answer. Below is a sketch of the proof.
I know that I can use the fact that $\langle V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n,
\otimes_n \rangle$ is a tensor product and can do the following

Given a $v \in V_{n + 1}$ define $\varphi_v : \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}}
V_i \rightarrow U$ by $\varphi_v (v_1, \ldots, v_n) = \varphi (v_1, \ldots,
v_n, v)$ which is clearly multilinear, hence there exist a linear map $k_v :
(V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_n)  \rightarrow U$ such that $k_v
\circ \otimes_n = \varphi_v$ because of the tensor product $\langle V_1
\otimes \cdots \otimes V_n, \otimes_n \rangle$.

We prove now that $k_v$ is linear in $v$. Let $u, v \in V_{n + 1}$, $\alpha
\in F$ and $w \in \otimes_n \left( \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}} V_i
\right)$ then there exist a $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ such that $w = \otimes_n
(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. Further
\begin{eqnarray*}
  k_{u + \alpha \cdot v} (w) & = & k_{u + \alpha \cdot v} (\otimes_n (v_1,
  \ldots, v_n))\\
  & = & \varphi_{u + \alpha \cdot v} (v_1, \ldots, v_n)\\
  & = & \varphi (v_1, \ldots, v_n, u + \alpha \cdot v)\\
  & = & \varphi (v_1, \ldots, v_n, u) + \alpha \cdot \varphi (v_1, \ldots,
  v_n, v)\\
  & = & \varphi_u (v_1, \ldots, v_n) + \alpha \cdot \varphi_v (v_1, \ldots,
  v_n)\\
  & = & k_u (\otimes_n (v_1, \ldots, v_n)) + \alpha \cdot k_v (\otimes_n
  (v_1, \ldots, v_n))\\
  & = & k_u (w) + \alpha \cdot k_v (w)
\end{eqnarray*}
proving that $k_{u + \alpha \cdot v} = k_u + \alpha \cdot k_v$.

Define $\psi : (V_1 \otimes_n \cdots \otimes_n V_n) \cdot V_{n + 1}
\rightarrow U \text{ by } \psi (u, v) = k_v (u)$ then we have  $\psi (x +
\alpha \cdot y, v) = k_v (x + \alpha \cdot y) = k_v (x) + \alpha \cdot k_v (y)
= \psi (x) + \alpha \cdot \psi (y)$ and $\psi (v, x + \alpha \cdot y) = k_{x +
\alpha \cdot y} (v) = k_x (v) + \alpha \cdot k_v (v) = \psi (v, x) + \alpha
\cdot \psi (v, y)$

From the above it follows that \ $\psi$ is multilinear. As $\langle (V_1
\otimes_n \cdots \otimes_n V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1}, \otimes \rangle$ is a
tensor space there exist a linear mapping $h : (V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes
V_n) \otimes V_{n + 1} \rightarrow U$ such that \ $h \circ \otimes = \psi$.
Let $(v_1, \ldots, v_{n + 1}) \in \prod_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n + 1 \}} V_i$
then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  (h \circ \otimes_{n + 1}) (v_1, \ldots, v_{n + 1}) & = & h (\otimes_{n + 1}
  (v_1, \ldots, v_{n + 1}))\\
  & = & h (\otimes (\otimes_n (v_1, \ldots, v_n), v_{n + 1}))\\
  & = & \psi (\otimes_n (v_1, \ldots, v_n), v_{n + 1})\\
  & = & k_{v_{n + 1}} (\otimes_n (v_1, \ldots, v_n))\\
  & = & \varphi_{v_{n + 1}} (v_1, \ldots, v_n)\\
  & = & \varphi (v_1, \ldots, v_n, v_{n + 1})
\end{eqnarray*}
which proves that \ $h \circ \otimes_{n + 1} = \varphi$.

It is a little bit more complex as in this text because we have to work with spans but I can solve this myself.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: what happens if you fix the last input? Note I corrected your definition, you need uniqueness of the induced linear map.

Comment: Actually you can proof that the induced map is unique (is a exercise in the book from Marvin Marcus), which is the reason why I did not required it in the definition.

Comment: In that case you need to assume the tensor product map is surjective in the sense that its image spans the target space.

Comment: Another hint: what can you say about the dependence of your $k=k_v$ on $v$? Consider $f$ defined by $f(t,v)=k_v(t)$.

Comment: You are correct about surjectivity, I forget to add (4) to the definition of a tensor product, that essentially covers surjectivity. Thanks for the hints I think I have my solution.